# Problem with event receiver in visual studio 2010

Tags: event-handling, field, sharepoint-2010, event-receiver

I am trying to figure out how to get the title of a list item from the base.ItemAdding(properties);
I know it's somewhere in properties, because what I want to do is copy the item that was just added to another list, meaning that the same item will be added to another list, can anyone help me get the the value of the fields from the item that was just added, such as title, description, ...

Thanks already.

Comment: Never mind, I found my error, I was using item is being added instead of item was added :P, silly me

Answer (score 1):

Hey - in the future if you are using the ItemAdding event - you can access properties from the AfterProperties collection

```
public override void ItemAdding(SPItemEventProperties properties)
       {

           String title = properties.AfterProperties["Title"].ToString();
```